# Accepting External parameter for a view in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a view which shows title and an image to the article where an image is uploaded within any post. This is shown through a block in a region.

It looks something like this:-

[image]

I show it on top of a landing page of a taxonomy; the landing page of the taxonomy page has all the articles which come under the respective taxonomy. Here lies the problem.

I want the article which is returned by the view to be from the taxonomy which shows it. Right now, an article is returned whichever has an uploaded Featured Image; what I Want is that the view returns an article which has an uploaded image and it belongs to the same category (taxonomy) of which landing page I am opening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Taxonomy Term ID contextual filter to the view. Then choose to provide a default argument, and under type choose Taxonomy Term ID from URL.

Comment: Thanks chronnus. As much as I hate to say it, do you have any tutorial/example in mind as how to do it? I am n0ob. :/

Comment: - Edit the view your are using

- Under Advanced -> Contextual Filters click on the add button.

- Check "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" and then click Apply.

- Under "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL" choose "Provide default value" and then under Type choose "Taxonomy Term ID from URL".

- Click on the Apply button and then save your view.